# how to remove popover when I leave

Tags: reactjs, antd, popover

what i use:react 18,antd 5.12.8,typescript 5.0.2

what is my problem:
I set Popover's trigger as hover,but when i input，moving the mouse to panel of choosing word ,it disappeard unexpectly
reproduce:[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ji-ben-antd-5-12-8-forked-s7kk9t?file=%2Fdemo.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0006356kibbrt8w6%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0002356kkkll5irs%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0003356k8wrzxzjs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0005356ke4gmuegl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr5tihdf0002356kkkll5irs%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0001356kutiwbawb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fdemo.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0002356kkkll5irs%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0001356kutiwbawb%2522%257D%252C%2522clr5tihdf0005356ke4gmuegl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0004356kcspelg3z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0005356ke4gmuegl%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0004356kcspelg3z%2522%257D%252C%2522clr5tihdf0003356k8wrzxzjs%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr5tihdf0003356k8wrzxzjs%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

---

---

I tried to solev it by eventListener,but failed.

I expect when I hover to panel of choosing words,it won't disappear.and only disappear when I leave the popover

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use this much logic for the action you want to perform.
Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, Popover, Input } from "antd";

const App: React.FC = () => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOpen = (newOpen: boolean) => {
      setOpen(newOpen);
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <Popover
        placement="rightTop"
        trigger="hover"
        overlayInnerStyle={{
          width: 300,
        }}
        title={<Input.Search className="nav-search" allowClear={true} />}
        open={open}
        onOpenChange={handleOpen}
        content={<>content111</>}
      >
        <Button id="trigger">
          打开popover
        </Button>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the code the `onOpenChange` prop uses the `handleOpen` function whenever the `Popover` is hovered as we have used a `trigger` of `hover` for it. Along with that the `open` prop value is set to the `boolean open` which is used along everytime we hover over the button.

Output :
[image: Popover]

Comment: It does  not work when I  input Chinese word，and this exception only occurs in Windows.maybe you can see the [video](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/46874)
I also wanna change the trigger prop from 'hover' to 'click',just like antd team said,but it would change user's behavior

Comment: hi @joey I looked through it and you can see that when you move your mouse to the Chinese suggestion toolbar the focus goes out of the popover making it disappear. By default `ant design` only has 3 event handler's for popovers: `click`, `hover` and `focus` [Ant Popover Triggers](https://ant.design/components/popover#popover-demo-triggertype) , what you said could possibly be not achieved by using ant popovers but if you make custom components than you might be able to achieve it , with hover and click handlers combination. So something like on over appear but only disappear when clicked out.

Comment: hi，thank you for answering my question.I had solved it by changing  the trigger prop to  `click`,and  PM also agreed this solution haha